# For each string.IndexOf(char) bug?

Tags: c#, .net, string, .net-4.5, indexof

```
var str = "GB29NWBK60161331926819"

foreach (var item in str.ToCharArray())
{
    Debug.WriteLine(str.IndexOf(item));
}
```

Gives the output

> 0
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5
>   1
>   7
>   8
>   9
>   10
>   8
>   10
>   13
>   13
>   10
>   3
>   2
>   8
>   19
>   10
>   3

I was expecting

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21

Is this or a bug or are my assumptions incorrect?

Comment: Pretty sure you mean `var item in str.ToCharArray()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it gives you the index of the first occurrence in your string.

look at your input string when it hits the 1 it gives you the index 10 and when it hits the next 1 it gives it to you again.

This is what the [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx) has to say to this method:

> Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of the specified string in this instance.

EDIT: `ElementAt(int index)` would expect an index. Using it would crash at the first letter `G`. It would take the UTF-16-Code of it which is 71 and break out of bounds.

your expectation would be satisfied by this:

```
var str = "GB29NWBK60161331926819";

for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: Your reference to ASCII is misleading. A string is a counted sequence of [Unicode](http://unicode.org/charts/nameslist/)'s [UTF-16](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) code units. ElementAt returns one of those UTF-16 code units.

Comment: Thanx for the hint. I will make an edit and correct it.

Answer (score 1):

You assumption is incorrect since the function return the first occurence matched in your string, if the function match nthing it will return -1

Answer (score 1):

Your expected output would be correct only for strings composed of unique characters.

This is absolutely not a bug, because your string has duplicates. `IndexOf` will not differentiate between `B` in `GB` and `B` in `BWBK` part, giving you the first index of the character in the string.